# Java GUI DiceRoll Application

Tags: java, user-interface, dice

I am currently working on a simple GUI application that rolls two dice. I am currently using two classes, one called "Game" and the other "DiceRoll". For meeting the assignment criteria, we have to use multiple classes in order for the program to work. It would be much easier just using one class...Anyways, I am successfully calling my "roll()" method in my "DiceRoll" class, which uses a switch statement and implements the "Graphics.drawImage()" method in order to draw the specified ".png" images. Everything looks fine, and I have no errors before I run it. When I run the program, the GUI frame pops up and all of the buttons/menus that I have created are working. However, once I press the "Roll Dice" button, I keep receiving multiple run-time errors.
This is what I have so far:

Game Class

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Game extends JFrame implements ActionListener 
{
JPanel mainPanel;
JPanel optionPanel;
JPanel dicePanel;
JButton rollDice;
JMenu options;
JMenuItem quit;
JMenuItem explanation;
JMenuBar menuBar;
JLabel diceLabel;
JLabel diceLabel2;
DiceRoll dr;
Graphics die1;
Graphics die2;

public Game()
{
    setTitle("Rollin' Dice");
    this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600,600));

    mainPanel = new JPanel();
    optionPanel = new JPanel();
    dicePanel = new JPanel();
    rollDice = new JButton("Roll Dice");
    options = new JMenu("Options");
    quit = new JMenuItem("Quit");
    explanation = new JMenuItem("Explanation");
    menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    dr = new DiceRoll();
    diceLabel = new JLabel();
    diceLabel2 = new JLabel();

    options.add(quit);
    options.add(explanation);

    menuBar.add(options);

    optionPanel.add(menuBar);
    optionPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600,100));

    dicePanel.add(rollDice);

    dicePanel.add(diceLabel);
    dicePanel.add(diceLabel2);

    mainPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600,600));
    mainPanel.add(optionPanel);
    mainPanel.add(dicePanel);


    quit.addActionListener(this);
    explanation.addActionListener(this);
    rollDice.addActionListener(this);

    this.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);

    this.pack();
    this.setVisible(true);
}


public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource()== quit)
        System.exit(0);

    if (e.getSource() == explanation)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(mainPanel,
                "Win: Roll a sum that is an even number \nLose: Roll a sum that is an odd number" + dicePanel, "Rules", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE); 
    }

    if (e.getSource() == rollDice)
    {

        dr.roll(die1);
        dr.roll(die2);

        diceLabel.updateUI();

        dicePanel.updateUI();
    }

}

public static void main (String []args)
{
    Game dg = new Game();
}
```

}

DiceRoll Class

```
    import java.awt.Graphics;
    import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
    import javax.imageio.*;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import javax.swing.JComponent;

public class DiceRoll extends JComponent {

private BufferedImage die1;
private BufferedImage die2;
private BufferedImage die3;
private BufferedImage die4;
private BufferedImage die5;
private BufferedImage die6;


public DiceRoll()
{
    try {
        die1 = (ImageIO.read(new File("die1.png")));
        die2 = ImageIO.read(new File("die2.png"));
        die3 = ImageIO.read(new File("die3.png"));
        die4 = ImageIO.read(new File("die4.png"));
        die5 = ImageIO.read(new File("die5.png"));
        die6 = ImageIO.read(new File("die6.png"));
    } catch (IOException ex){
        System.err.println("That is invalid");
    }
}


public Graphics roll(Graphics g)
{
    int dieResult = (int)(6 * Math.random());

    switch(dieResult){
    case 1: 
        g.drawImage(die1, 0, 0, null);
        break;
    case 2:
        g.drawImage(die2, 0, 0, null);
        break;
    case 3:
        g.drawImage(die3, 0, 0, null);
        break;
    case 4:
        g.drawImage(die4, 0, 0, null);
        break;
    case 5:
        g.drawImage(die5, 0, 0, null);
        break;
    case 6:
        g.drawImage(die6, 0, 0, null);
        break;
    }
    return g;
}
```

}

Errors that I am receiving

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at DiceRoll.roll(DiceRoll.java:51)
at Game.actionPerformed(Game.java:89)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: So now, my question is...
How can I get these dice images to show up in the dicePanel?
Do I need to place them inside labels?
When I try to add die1 and die2 to the dicePanel, Eclipse states that I need to set them as Components...but won't they need to be of the Graphics type in order to actually "draw" these images

Comment: Please give details of the errors. Include the full stack trace.

Comment: Could you please post the full exception trace for your first error, so we're able to better help you.

Comment: Ok, I added the errors that I was receiving. Much appreciated on the quick response! Please let me know if there is anything else you need me to post to make it as clear as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're making this much more complicated than is necessary. Why don't you change your `public Graphics roll(Graphics g)` method to calculate the roll and update the `JLabel`, something like this...

```
public void roll(JLabel dieLabel) {
    int dieResult = (int)(6 * Math.random());
    dieLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon("die" + dieResult + ".png"))
}
```

Then all you need to do is change your code here ...

```
if (e.getSource() == rollDice){
    dr.roll(die1);
    dr.roll(die2);
    diceLabel.updateUI();
    dicePanel.updateUI();
}
```

to send the label you want to change, like this...

```
if (e.getSource() == rollDice){
    dr.roll(diceLabel);
    dr.roll(diceLabel2);
}
```

You pass the `JLabel` through to the `roll()` method, which calculates the roll and sets the image on that label. Much simpler.

This also means that you don't need the 2 `Graphics` objects either (`die1` and `die2`), so you can get rid of these. You also wouldn't need the `BufferedImages`, because the loading of the image file is done by the `ImageIcon` class

Let me know if you need any further information about my suggestion, for learning purposes.

EDIT...

This is my re-writing of your `Game()` constructor, that shows how to add items to `JPanels` using `GridLayout` and `BorderLayout` as the layout managers...

```
public Game(){
    // Set the JFrame properties
    setTitle("Rollin' Dice");
    this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600,600));

    // Create the main JPanel to hold the interface
    mainPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());


    // Build the Menu
    options = new JMenu("Options");

    quit = new JMenuItem("Quit");
    options.add(quit);

    explanation = new JMenuItem("Explanation");
    options.add(explanation);

    menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    menuBar.add(options);

    // Add the menu to the top of the main panel
    mainPanel.add(menuBar,BorderLayout.NORTH);


    // Create the dice
    dr = new DiceRoll();
    diceLabel = new JLabel();
    diceLabel2 = new JLabel();

    dicePanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2,1));
    dicePanel.add(diceLabel);
    dicePanel.add(diceLabel2);

    // Add the dicePanel to the center of the main panel
    mainPanel.add(dicePanel,BorderLayout.CENTER);


    // Add the rollDice button to the bottom of the main panel
    rollDice = new JButton("Roll Dice");
    mainPanel.add(rollDice,BorderLayout.SOUTH);


    // Add listeners to the menu items and buttons
    quit.addActionListener(this);
    explanation.addActionListener(this);
    rollDice.addActionListener(this);

    // Add the main panel to the JFrame
    this.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);

    // Show the JFrame
    this.pack();
    this.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: I've implemented your suggestions and it seems to be working. However, whenever I press the "Roll Dice" button now, nothing happens on the actual JFrame and nothing is appearing in the Console (which is good because before there were massive amounts of errors, so thank you!). Will I need to add the dieLabel to the mainPanel or the dicePanel in the Game class? Also, thank you very much for your input. I feel as if I am really close to getting this but it's so very frustrating. -_-

Comment: For your `JPanels`, you aren't using any layout, so it probably doesn't know how to show the items. I actually think your `diceLabel2` probably overwrites `diceLabel` on your layout. You should probably learn to use LayoutManagers so you can arrange your panels properly - see this URL http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html for more information. I would suggest your `dicePanel` should be `dicePanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2,1));` and your other panels should probably be `new BorderLayout();`. Have a look at implementing some of these first, and see if that helps.

Comment: I'm trying to rearrange them now, but the dice are STILL not appearing. I think I know what you mean though. Are you saying that the dice ARE appearing, but they are just in an uncreated layout, so they are not appearing on the actual GUI itself?

Comment: Well, if you don't define a layout for a `JPanel`, every time you run `JPanel.add()` the last item you added will overwrite all the previously added items. So, if you wanted to show 2 dice side-by-side in the same `JPanel`, you would have to set the layout as a `GridLayout` (ie `panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2,1));`. When you do this, calling `add()` the first time adds the item into the first cell of the grid, and `add()` the second time adds the item into the second cell. Therefore, both items appear on the panel rather than having them overwrite each other.

Comment: I have edited my answer to show how I would construct your interface using LayoutManagers - see above. If you do something like this, and it still doesn't work, the next thing would be to check whether your button is actually working. To do this, its usually simple enough to add a line to your `actionPerformed()` method that just says `System.out.println("I am here");`, and checking your console output to see whether this text was written there or not.

Comment: I just logged back into the account TODAY and realized that I forgot to thank you because I implemented your coding and it worked! THank you very much and incredibly sorry for the late response!

Comment: No problem :-). All you need to do is click the 'tick' button next to my answer to show that your problem was resolved. This helps other people to see what the resolution was (in case they have a similar problem), and it also thanks the answerer for their help.

Answer (score 2):

You pass `null`  here:

```
dr.roll(die1);
dr.roll(die2);
```

As you never instantiate `die1` and `die2`, and you get **NullPointerException**.

Comment: What do I instantiate them to? I tried to instantiate them with the Graphics() class, but it said I had to instantiate them as Components... I'm at a loss of what to do

Comment: I think you need to override paintComponent, take a look at this example: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/ExtendsJComponenttocreatedrawingpad.htm

Comment: Do you mean the roll() method? Because there is no paintComponent method.